# Cuban cigars: From Cuba to Greece to USA

Tags: usa, cuba

My brother brought me some Cuban cigars from his visit in Cuba. I am flying to US soon, from Greece, and I want to take them with me. Would this pose any kind of problem in the borders and customs at the airport? A quick Google search says that there would be no problem but I am not sure.

If they make a random check on my luggage and found them would there be any consequences?

Answer (score 2):

On October 14, 2016, then-President Obama issued a [Presidential Policy Directive -- United States-Cuba Normalization](https://obamawhitehouse.archives.gov/the-press-office/2016/10/14/presidential-policy-directive-united-states-cuba-normalization) that lifted sanctions, including the $100 limit on Cuban cigars and alcohol.

You would include cigars on a passenger declaration card (as appropriate or specific to you).

Per USCIS:

> [Travelers bringing in tobacco products (Cigarettes, Cigars, Bidis) into the U.S. for personal use.](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/53/%7E/travelers-bringing-in-tobacco-products)
>
> Returning resident travelers, for those over the age of 21, may import tobacco products only in quantities not exceeding the amounts specified in the personal exemptions for which the traveler qualifies (not more than 200 cigarettes and 100 cigars if arriving from other than a beneficiary country and insular possession).
>
> For more information about duty-exemption or duty rates for other tobacco products, please contact the [Ports of Entry](http://www.cbp.gov/contact/ports) directly.